# Ошибка при создании бина

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Выходит ошибка при компиляции ругается на то что не может создать бин `ContactDaoImpl` потому что в классе `UserRole` не правильно использован `@OneToMany`, а это два разных не связанных класса.

Собственно вот эти классы

`UserRole`

```
class UserRole {

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "user_roles",
        uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(
                columnNames = { "role", "username" }))
    public class UserRole{

    private Integer userRoleId;
    private User user;
    private String role;

    public UserRole() {
    }

    public UserRole(User user, String role) {
        this.user = user;
        this.role = role;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "user_role_id",
            unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getUserRoleId() {
        return this.userRoleId;
    }

    public void setUserRoleId(Integer userRoleId) {
        this.userRoleId = userRoleId;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "username", nullable = false)
    public User getUser() {
        return this.user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Column(name = "role", nullable = false, length = 45)
    public String getRole() {
        return this.role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

}
```

`ContactDaoImpl`

```
class ContactDaoImpl {

    @Repository
    public class ContactDAOImpl implements ContactDAO {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void addContact(Contact contact) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(contact);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Contact> listContact() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Contact").list();
    }

    public void removeContact(Integer id) {
        Contact contact = (Contact) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().load(
                Contact.class, id);
        if (null != contact) {
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(contact);
        }

    }
}
```

Стектрэйс:

> `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException`: Error creating bean with name `'contactDAOImpl'`: Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested 
>   exception is `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException`: Could not
>   autowire field: `public org.hibernate.SessionFactory 
>   kz.tanikin.springtest.dao.ContactDAOImpl.sessionFactory`; nested exception is `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException`:
>   Error creating bean 
>   with name `'sessionFactory'` defined in `ServletContext` resource [`/WEB-INF/spring/data.xml`]: Invocation of init method failed; nested
>   exception is 
>   `org.hibernate.AnnotationException`: Use of `@OneToMany` or `@ManyToMany` 
>   targeting an unmapped class: 
>   `springtest.domain.User.userRole[springtest.domain.UserRole]`

В чем может быть дело?
Могу предоставить дополнительную информацию

data.xml

```
<bean id="userDao" class="kz.tanikin.springtest.dao.UserDaoImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="myUserDetailsService"
      class="kz.tanikin.springtest.service.MyUserDetailsService">
    <property name="userDao" ref="userDao" />
</bean>
```

и выходит ошибка

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains':
>   Cannot resolve reference to bean
>   'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0' while
>   setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0]; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0':
>   Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#7bd95c47' of type
>   [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter]
>   while setting constructor argument with key [3]; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name '(inner bean)#7bd95c47': Cannot resolve
>   reference to bean
>   'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices#0'
>   while setting constructor argument with key [1]; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices#0':
>   Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#232efad5' while setting
>   constructor argument; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name '(inner bean)#232efad5': Bean instantiation
>   via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService]:
>   Factory method 'cachingUserDetailsService' threw exception; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException:
>   More than one UserDetailsService registered. Please use a specific Id
>   reference in   or  elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring жалуется на то, что не может создать бин `contactDAOImpl`. Он не может заинжектить в него `sessionFactory`. А это у него не получается, потому что он не может создать бин `sessionFactory`. А это, в свою очередь, происходит из-за некорректного использования аннотации `@ManyToOne` в классе `UserRole`. Скорее всего, вы не перечислили класс `User` в конфиге Hibernate. Или, как вариант, вы пометили класс `User` аннотацией `org.hibernate.annotations.Entity` вместо `javax.persistence.Entity`.

Comment: @JTan, смотрите последнюю строчку *More than one `UserDetailsService` registered. Please use a specific Id reference in or elements.* Спринг подцепил по какой-то причине несколько экземпляров менеджеров пользовательских учеток и не знает, какую использовать.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо